# Media Query not taking format like it should

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am designing a container on my site and for some reason, whenever my media query takes place, my code does not turn out like it should. Every where I put my code it works (jsfddle, snippet), but on site the bottom arrow is going inside of the blue container.

Why is the blue down arrow where it needs to be in the snippet, but not my website?

Please go here: [click here](http://optimumwebdesigns.com/discuss-project)

```css
.arrow_box {
 position: relative;
 background: #88b7d5;
 border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
 top: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
 border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
 border-top-color: #88b7d5;
 border-width: 30px;
 margin-left: -30px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
 border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
 border-top-color: #c2e1f5;
 border-width: 36px;
 margin-left: -36px;
}
#project-content-wrap {
  margin: 10% 5%;
}
#project-box-title1 {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #FFF;
}
#project-box-title2 {
  font-size: 3.2em;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#project-box-description {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #303030;
  margin-top: 40px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow_box">
  <div id="project-content-wrap">
    <div id="project-box-title1">KICK START YOUR</div>
    <div id="project-box-title2">PROJECT</div>
    <div id="project-box-description">We enjoy partnering with established brands from all over the globe. To begin the process please provide us with a high level overview and submit our form. We will review and respond promptly.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Try to upload a screenshot. It looks fine over here? Btw, where is you media query?

Comment: @Lars I uploaded a snippet of what I see. My media query is in my actual code.

Comment: It looks off for me in Chrome and FF in your url, looks fine here on SO. The only thing I can think of is maybe, say, SO has margins and padding reset for you, or vice versa.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Right, that is why I don't understand what is going on. I have resets within my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At line 93 of discuss-project.css the `margin-top` is set to `-26px`. Remove that and it should be like you want.

Comment: Perfect, well kind of. That was in my main desktop view, so it had a purpose, but I went into my media query in the `.arrow_box:before {` section and did `margin-top: 0;` Thanks !

Comment: Ah, ofcourse, forgot to mention that. Glad it's fixed

Answer (score 0):

On the media-queries part, just add a `0px left margin` on your .arrow_box:before.

```
.arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-top-color: #c2e1f5;
    border-width: 36px;
    margin-left: -36px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

The issue was simple: it was keeping your initial `margin-left:-36px` of the arrow when screen-size>640px.
Tested under Chrome, Firefox, IE and Safari